# How can I download image from local share folder Pc?

Tags: c#

I'm write this code for display the image from other PC in local network:

```
string path = Path.Combine(@"\\BEHZAD-PC\foodimage", label1.Text+".jpg");
if(File.Exists(path))
{
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = path;
}
```

but image not show to my application,where is the problem?please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The user should have permission to the image to be able to view it, In my opinion this is not a good practice, as too many variables are there in order to be able to view the image, I suggest you to copy the image to your local drive and show it form there.

Comment: i shared the foodimage my friend

Comment: i think other pc can not access the this share folder

Comment: as i said, there is permission issue in this case, you can track it by trying to access the image by the user directly through windows, are you able to view the image?

Comment: please help me step by step create permission and i follow your solution.

Comment: what dose label1.Text contains, are you sure that the combined path is correct, try to add the static path directly and test it, something like this @"\\server\Test\some-file-that-exists.pdf"

Comment: i test string path = Path.Combine(@"\\BEHZAD-PC\foodimage","8.jpg"); this,but so now show

Comment: i have two PC on my wireless network:BEHZAD-PC-->image on it,and ASUS:PC want to show image on BEHZAD-PC

Comment: when i ping BEHZAD-PC with ASUS ping reply,but when i ping ASUS with BEHZAD-PC ping request-time out message

Comment: i think this is your problem, try to configure the network correctly between the tow machines

Comment: i have wireless modem,and this modem set ip on my two machine.

Comment: can you give the shared file permission read to everyone and try again?